# Bug: Mobile user page on meta shows reputation gains

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation

Despite the fact that no reputation is gained on meta, I still see +5 and +10 in the "reputation" section on the *mobile* user page.

Note that this does not actually add to my reputation, only that it mistakenly looks like it does. <strike>I'd post a screenshot if there was a way to do that on the mobile website.</strike> (Apparently, I can't add new tags from here, either).

[image: screenshot of user's daily reputation summary on a child meta site]

Can anybody else confirm this?
Any stackexchange mods?

Comment: No response, so I cross-posted this to meta.SO.

Comment: Cross-posting isn't recommended.  It just means that one post will get resolved and then this one is stuck around and looks unresolved.  Doesn't help keep things clean.  At the very least if you really, truly want it on MSO, ask for a migration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been resolved [per the cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116394/140548).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the mobile page hasn't caught up with the recent user-profile changes.  Until that change the regular web site had a reputation link that showed you that too, and if you hover over your name at the top of any page on meta you'll still see the "+X" entries with question links, just as if reputation were really calculated here.

I assume that the same underlying code runs on both meta and main and that meta then overrides the reporting of reputation. Except not completely, as you've discovered.